# EditText setError() with icon but without Popup message

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to to have some validation for my EditText wherein I want to show "[image]" icon (that comes when you put `editText.setError("blah blah"))` but don't want the text in the popup displaying that "blah blah".

Is there any way to do it? One way is to create a custom layout which will show the image icon in the EditText. But is there any better solution?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Problem solved after a lot of research and permutations- (Also thanks to @van)

Create a new class that will extend `EditText` something like this-

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
    setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null);
}
}
```

Use this class as a view in your xml like this-

```
<com.raj.poc.MyEditText
    android:id="@+id/et_test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now in the third step, just set a `TextWatcher` to your custom text view like this-

```
    et = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.et_test);

    errorIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_error);
    errorIcon.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, errorIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), errorIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()));
       et.setError(null,errorIcon);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().length()>6){
                et.setError("", null);
            }else{
                et.setError("", errorIcon);
            }
        }
    });
```

where `R.drawable.ic_error` = [image]

Keeping text null solves the problem
But if we keep only null in setError(null), this won't show the validation error; it should be null along with second param.

Comment: This way the icon won't disappear when text is changed.

Comment: @Vincent : Please try the updated answer. This works on 4.2 as well and solves your problem. Thanks though.

Comment: saved my life. Works perfectly!

Comment: To get the error-icon without an error-message-popup only when `setError("");` is called, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664299/5433102

Comment: Please help me, its not working for me.. i have applied the same, and one important thing is that, my main theme extends from '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar'

Answer (score 14):

You dont need to create a new `EditText` class or change xml. The solution is very simple:

```
Edittext editText= (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);

String str= editText.getText().toString();

if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){

                Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.error); 
                                 //add an error icon to yur drawable files
                dr.setBounds(0, 0, dr.getIntrinsicWidth(), dr.getIntrinsicHeight());

                editText.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,dr,null);

            }
```

Comment: `editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.error, 0);` also works and is shorter.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess This should be the accepted solution. You have just saved me! Thanks man! :D

Answer (score 4):

Sorry Rajkiran, but your solution is not working on Android 4.2 version. If I am trying to set `null` value for error, it is not even displayed. The solution I came up was to extend `EditText` and override `setError` method. No I have only error indicator without popup.

```
@Override
public void setError(CharSequence pError, Drawable pIcon) {
    setCompoundDrawables(null, null, pIcon, null);
}
```

Comment: Yes. Because I faced the same problem as you and that was the first solution I came up with. Feel free to try this.

Comment: Ohh, I'll surely have a go at this solution. If this works on all android versions and satisfies commment#1 on my answer, I'll accept your answer instead of mine. :)

Comment: Well @van unfortunately your code did not work for me. I don't know why. But yes that helped me optimize my answer. Please check my updated answer. But still upvoted your answer. You can already see that right?

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with the same problem. I wanted to use `.setError()` to my `EditText` when user insert null input. But I think the pop-out message is annoying, especially when you have more `EditText`s.
My solution was naive and simple, but it worked on all devices I've tried so far.

I created my own class myEditText and just `@Override` this method:

```
    @Override
    public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
       setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null);
    }
```

then use in `layout.xml`

```
    <cz.project.myEditText
     ...
    />
```

and finally in my code
I put `onFocusChangeListener` to `myEditText`, so when someone clicks-in, the icon disappears.

```
    myEditText input = (myEditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            input.setError(null);
    });

    if(val == null) input.setError("");
```

It works Exactly how I want = no pop-up message when `.setError()` is called on `EditText`.

Answer (score 1):

To get only the error-icon without an error-message-popup **only when `setError("")` is called** (i.e. set an empty String as error-message) I use a custom EditText-class where I override `setError(CharSequence, Drawable)` like this:

```
@Override
public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
    if (error == null) {
        super.setError(null, icon);
        setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
    }
    else if (error.toString().equals("")) setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null);
    else super.setError(error, icon);
}
```

Everything else stays the same:

Use `setError(null)` to get neither the icon nor the message-popup.

Use `setError(errorMessage)`, where `errorMessage` is a String with length 1 at least, to get the icon and message-popup.

Answer (score -2):

This is the very useful when you want to show the error messages for the edittext field when the user enter wrong information.this is very simply program only you have to use serError() method in the edittext.

Step 1:
Create button and implement onclickListener.

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
```

Step 2:
Validate the input fields and set the error in the input field.

```
if(edName.length()>3){
if(edNumber.length()>3){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
edNumber.setError("Number Mininum length is 4");
}
}else{
edName.setError("Name Mininum length is 4");
}
```

Refer this  link for more:http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2014/08/set-error-message-in-edittext-android.html

Comment: Could you please read the title again? It says - EditText setError() with icon but WITHOUT POPUP MESSAGE.