# Customizing the setError icon for EditText

Tags: android, icons, textview

I want to set a `setError` method to my `EditText`, with a custom icon instead of the default Android icon. So I tried this:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTitle)).setError(getResources().getText(R.string.errEmptyTitle), 
         getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ico_warning_small);
```

It shows me the custom message, but not the custom icon. I tried this as well:

```
Drawable warning = (Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ico_warning_small);
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTitle))
      .setError(getResources().getText(R.string.errEmptyTitle), warning);
```

Pretty much the same, but I still decided to give it a go. However this also didn't help - I still can't see the icon.
I tried to use some other Android system icon, just to see if I see them and no, I don't see them as well.

So what am I doing wrong? Is there any way to set that custom icon?

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985295/edittext-seterror-with-icon-but-without-popup-message

Comment: @Steelight Thank you very much, it worked! Could you please make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is discussed and resolved here:

[EditText setError() with icon but without Popup message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985295/edittext-seterror-with-icon-but-without-popup-message)

I hope that by extending the answer it would not get auto-converted to a comment.

Answer (score 48):

You need to set the bounds on the drawable before using it in setError.

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
editText.setError("error", drawable);
```

Comment: THANKS - spent an hour on this!

Comment: making a fresh drawable using canvas and paint, the getIntrinsicWidth and getIntrinsicHeight return -1, any clues why?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to show any icon at all, use

```
editText.setError("error", null);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    Drawable customErrorDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.error_icon);
        customErrorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, customErrorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), customErrorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());


 editText.setError("please enter data",customErrorDrawable);
```