# How to set TextField is empty using Text Utils in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Edit Text TextUtils.isEmpty]

I am having a problem with Edit Text empty text.

1. If email and password textfield is empty, then the TextUtils gonna show on both edittext.
2. If the user press the **exclamation icon**, then the message"This field is required" **gonna show up**. Other than that, its gonna be exclamation only.

Below is my code in ASIDE

```
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

     if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        etEmail.setError("This field is required");
        return;
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        etEmail.setError("This field is required");
        return;
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        etPassword.setError("This field is required");
        return;
    }
    else{
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
    etEmail.setError("This field is required");
    etPassword.setError("This field is required");
    return;
}
else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
    etEmail.setError("This field is required");
    return;
}
else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
    etPassword.setError("This field is required");
    return;
}
else{
}
```

Now it shows in the both Edittext fields.

Comment: thanks it works now. but how about my second question, about  the icon? do you have any idea?

Comment: displaying error is depend upon focus so once edittext will get focus it will display error. you can't set focus on multiple edittext.

Comment: Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707282/customizing-the-seterror-icon-for-textview