# Android TextInputLayout icon in error (or hint) text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable

I am using a `TextInputLayoutHelper` widget in order to follow the material guidelines for floating label inputs. It currently looks like this:

[image: floating input label with error message]

### My code

In my activities `onCreate` function, I have:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val passwordInputLayout = this.findViewById<TextInputLayoutHelper>(R.id.input_layout_password)
    passwordInputLayout.error = "8+ characters and at least one uppercase letter, a number, and a special character (\$, #, !)"
    passwordInputLayout.isErrorEnabled = true
}
```

and my widget in my `xml` looks like...

```
<TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorAppearance"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/asl_password_visibility"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="?colorControlNormal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/set_a_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</TextInputLayout>
```

### What I want to do

I want to put an icon in the error/hint text (the exclamation triangle) to the right of the error text.

[image: mock up of input with error icon]

### My Attempt

#### Attempt 1

[I found an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13707282/1554860) which uses `setError(text, drawable)` but I am using `Kotlin` to `setError` is not available.

So I tried:

```
val warningIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_warning_black_24dp, null)
warningIcon?.setBounds(0, 0, warningIcon.intrinsicWidth, warningIcon.intrinsicHeight)

passwordInputLayout.error = "8+ characters and at least one uppercase letter, a number, and a special character (\$, #, !) $warningIcon"
```

but that does not render the drawable, only a string of the resource path.

#### Attempt 2

I found [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9161958/1554860) that overrides the `TextInputLayoutHelper` in order to set a drawable next to the text. As you can see, `setError` only contains the interface `override fun setError(error: CharSequence?)` which does not have a parameter for `drawable`.

```
override fun setError(error: CharSequence?) {
    super.setError(error)

    val warningIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_warning_black_24dp, null)
    warningIcon?.setBounds(0, 0, warningIcon.intrinsicWidth, warningIcon.intrinsicHeight)
    // mHelperView is a TextView used in my custom `TextInputLayout` override widget
    mHelperView!!.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, warningIcon, null)
}
```

---

Is there an override or built in "Android way" to add this icon next to the error/hint text?

Comment: What about putting all the edittext inside a frame layout and putting a view above it?

Comment: @UrielFrankel my only hesitation with an implementation like that is I wanted to stick with "the native Android" way of doing things by using the `app:errorEnabled` and `app:errorTextAppearance` to control the styling/position of my errors. I don't want to have to worry about positioning my error text anytime I want to use an icon. But that is definitely a valid way around this problem I am having, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use SpannableString with ImageSpan like this

```
val errorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.ic_error)
your_text_input_layout.error = SpannableString("your string").apply {
                setSpan(ImageSpan(errorDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

Comment: the idea is workable if set the spannable string base on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177667/1083128

Answer (score 0):

This might help others who've fallen in to similar trouble. I looked at source codes. The thing is `setError(text, drawable)` has defined in EditText class not `TextInputLayout` as your layout is based on.

I have similar code and issue like you and since [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) doesn't have any method to replace Drawable then we have to create a TextView below TextInputLayout in order to simulate error message.

Comment: the request of this question is to place the icon on the right side of the error message, your suggestion is to place the icon on the right side of the edit text.

Answer (score 0):

You want to place an icon inside the error container of `TextInputLayout`

If you check the real layout

[image]

You'll find that your textview is even wrap content.

Also in SDK sources

```
if (enabled) {
    mErrorView = new AppCompatTextView(getContext());
    mErrorView.setId(R.id.textinput_error);
    ...
```

So there is no place to insert an icon on the right AS IS.

- One possible solution is to find this view programatically inside your layout, change width and apply drawable.
- Second (and probably easiest) solution is to implement your own simple error layout and not to set error for `TextInputLayout` but manage the error state by yourself