# Android SetColorFilter() vs. SetBackgroundResource() / SetColorBackground()

Tags: android, android-edittext, background-color

Can anyone explain this difference in appearance?
SetColorFilter() acts on the background Drawable, whether setBackgroundResource() sets the background color.
In Android version 2.3 I safely used SetColorFilter() to alter the background color of EditText, since it is very easy to restore the original color by clearing the filter. No need to get and remember it. Now there seems to be a difference between the two ways.

This is an EditTextPreference dialog box, et is the EditText id.

```
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String source = s.toString();
            et.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            if( !source.matches("^[0-9]+$") ) {
                et.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.invalid), Mode.OVERLAY);
                et.invalidate();
                et.selectAll();
            } else {
                et.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                et.invalidate();
            }
            et.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
```

[image]

And this is the same code using SetBackgroundResource()

```
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String source = s.toString();
            et.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            if( !source.matches("^[0-9]+$") ) {
                et.setBackgroundResource(R.color.invalid);
                et.selectAll();
            } else {
                et.setBackgroundResource(R.color.valid);
            }
            et.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You know you can just call `et.setError("Error message");` and it will mark that edittext with an error icon. Just as another option.

Comment: @dymmeh Would you put your comment as answer? I tried it, I have a snapshot, I can post it for the sake of any other user. As you said there is an icon. I would very much like to have a red background also.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `textView.setError("Error message")` as mentioned above.
If you want to customize the behavior of setError() however (such as changing background color), you will sadly enough need to override EditText and write your own handler for setError, as shown here: [EditText setError() with icon but without Popup message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985295/edittext-seterror-with-icon-but-without-popup-message)