# Can EditText's error message icon be changed?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, icons

In `EditText`, errors can be set programmatically like this:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nameEditText.getText()))
     nameEditText.setError(getString("This field is required"));
```

And as a result, this would show up:

[image]

Is there any way to change the error icon to an image or `drawable`?

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985295/edittext-seterror-with-icon-but-without-popup-message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `setError(CharSequence, Drawable)`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nameEditText.getText()))
 nameEditText.setError(getString("This field is required"),iconDrawable);
```

where `iconDrawable` is a `Drawable`

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable icon = 
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_error_icon);
if (icon != null) {
icon.setBounds(0, 0, 
             icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
             icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
}
editText.setError(“Error test”, icon);
```

Comment: Using set bound would make it work, else it wouldn't work