# Android - EditText error changes position on keyboard open/close

Tags: android

I am using `editText.setError()` attribute but the onKeyboard open/close the error float message changes position to be many pixels higher than the editText instead of being right under it.

I have added:`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the activity at the manifest file and at the `EditText` xml.

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985295/edittext-seterror-with-icon-but-without-popup-message) this. You can find the answer.

and see [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-show-error-in-edittext/) example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah,that's your xml maybe some error.you can Modify the layout ，mostly the  edittext layout group ,you should change the background to transparent bellow the windowSoft. In a word ,take notice the layout ,Clever use of transparent at the bottom .