# Android: Validation symbol in EditText

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

We have the `setError` method for setting an error message with a red exclamation symbol at the end of the box if validation of an EditText returns false:

[image: validation returned false]

I want to set a **green tick symbol**, just like the red exclamation at the end of the box when my validation returns true:

```
password.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {

                if (password.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    password.setError("Password should be greater than 6 characters!");
                }
                else {
                    //validation is true, so what to put here?
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT 1**
Seemingly impossible, but there's more to the problem. I did this:

```
email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                String mail = email.getText().toString();
                if(!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail).matches()) {
                    email.setError("Please enter a valid email address");
                } 
                else {
                    Log.i("yay!","Email is valid!!!");
                    email.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.validated, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Though I can see in my logs that `yay: Email is valid!!!`, I can't see the validation symbol at the end of the `EditText`.

However, to my surprise when I change the `if` statement to always `false`, I can see both the symbol with the log statement.

Any explanations upon why could this be happening?

Comment: [check out this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9161958/2183890)

Comment: Why do you need a green checkmark? There either is no error, or there is an error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested it out in my own project using `setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon)`

1. Get a new Icon:
   Go to my drawable folder
   adding a new vector asset.
   I picked "material icon" and browse, 
   then picked ic_done_24pp.
2. Color:
   Next, I went into the xml and made it green by changing the fillcolor:
   `android:fillColor="#FF00FF00"`

3: Change code:

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_done_24dp); 
myIcon.setBounds(0, 0, myIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), myIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
mPasswordView.setError("Good", myIcon);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works very clean without causing any other errors.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the pop-up message?

Comment: @Android-er just don't pass any string(first argument)

Comment: Passing "" to the error message does not remove the pop-up message. It still shows that pop-up but without text.

Comment: To remove error popup just set - mEditText.setError(null);

Answer (score 8):

You can show `drawableRight` when your validation is true.

```
password.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.rightImage, 0);
```

and set it back to normal when validation is false.

```
password.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works exactly as I wanted!

Comment: A new inexplicable problem has arised. Please see the update on the question.

Comment: @Akeshwar use `email.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);` in if part and `email.setError(null);` in else part