# How to remove the Error message box from setError in android?

Tags: android

By default, the `setError` makes an `EditText` look like the following:

[image: setError view]

There's a red exclamation. The error message pops-up when that particular `EditText` gains focus.

I'm creating a custom `setError` method:

```
validatedIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.validated);
validatedIcon.setBounds(0, 0, validatedIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), validatedIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
firstName.setError("Please check your first name",validatedIcon);
```

My new error icon is a custom icon. But I don't want the error message to be displayed with it. I tried passing null as the message, but that removed the whole icon. I tried passing the empty string, but that simply made an empty box.

**Alternative tried**: I tried setting the icon using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`, but even after much hair-pulling, it didn't work properly.

So, is there a way to get rid of the message-box in `setError`?

Comment: Check this out. Same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985295/edittext-seterror-with-icon-but-without-popup-message

Answer (score 1):

As Patel Hiren suggested in the comment, creating a custom class that extends `EditText` and overriding the `setError` method there solved my issue:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
        setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null);
    }
}
```

Also, in my layout file, I had to replace `EditText` with the fully qualified name (which is `packagename.className`) of this class. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set where you want firstName.setError(null);

Comment: This'll remove the error symbol also. I just want to remove the error text, not the symbol.

Comment: You just want to error symbol right. you can try this public class MyEditText extends EditText {

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
    setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null);
}
}