# EditText valid input indicator

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have a validation for an editText where a user inputs an id. The id has a minimum length of 6 and has error detection. I want to inform the user when a **correct** id is entered right away. I've searched online and most of what i've found is the case of telling the user of invalid input through methods like `editText.setError()`. So my question is, is there a `setError` equivalent for when the user has done the correct thing.

Comment: what are the conditions to enter a correct id ? at least 6 caracters and I guess be unique ? And how would you like to display the message ?

Comment: I want to display it as `setError` displays errors, only with a green indicator to tell success

Comment: i can do success indication by displaying a `Toast`, but that isn't as preferable as the status `setError` displays when there is an error. I want to display success as `setError` displays error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TextChangeListener to perform events when the user changes the text.

```
textEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      // validate text and inform user
   }
});
```

Comment: i do watch for the user's text changes, my question is about displaying a *_success_* indicator when the user gets it right, keep in mind the id can be long so i want to give a direct feedback when the user inputs the right id

Comment: Ah.  I don't think there is an official one, but maybe you could customize the icon to produce the effect you're looking for? This question shows how to subclass and change the icon, though they are also disabling the text. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985295/edittext-seterror-with-icon-but-without-popup-message

Comment: Thnx, that is exactly what i wanted. Just display an appropriate icon.

Answer (score 0):

We can set the style of the *setError* popup with *fromHtml* method.

You can also use this : https://github.com/sherifelkhatib/WidgyWidgets